# tns doctor says "not able to configure your environment for local builds", thus "tns run ios" not working

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript. I installed NativeScript and the CLI. To diagnose if everything is installed correctly, I run tns doctor which says two things:-

1. WARNING: Xcode version 9.4.1 is lower than minimum required version 10. 
   Now I am not sure if this could be the reason behind tns run ios not working.
2. Not able to configure local environment for ios and the exact message is :-
   The setup script was not able to configure your environment for local builds. To execute local builds, you have to set up your environment manually. Please consult our setup instructions here 'https://docs.nativescript.org/start/quick-setup'.

To continue, choose one of the following options:  Skip Step and Configure Man
ually

> TypeError: this.$injector.resolve(...).out is not a function
>       at Errors. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:148:54)
>       at Generator.throw ()
>       at rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/common/errors.js:5:65)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

If I try `tns run ios` then it brings me this list of things to be installed (which are already installed):-
This setup script will request to install the following on your machine:

1. Homebrew
2. Google Chrome
3. Open JDK 8
4. Android SDK
5. Android emulator system image
6. HAXM (Hardware accelerated Android emulator)
7. Android emulator
8. CocoaPods
9. CocoaPods setup
10. pip
11. six
12. xcodeproj

and even if I continue with install it ends up at the exact same where it says that it fail to configure for local environment.

Comment: The *tns* tag is for an Oracle database specific protocol. I doubt that is the intention. Please remove it if it does not apply.

Comment: Have you tried updating your xcode?

Comment: Thanks Narendra. I had to update my OS first and then I updated my Xcode to version 10. After that when I did tns run ios then it successfully launched the app in ios simulator. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem, i found that

Run that command:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Since after OS and then Xcode update to version 10 solved it for me. I never had this issue again.